# Loop is not working as console is not printing Hello

Tags: python

```
maharashtra = []
maharashtradata = []
for sec in sections:
    row = 1
    for item in xmlDocTree.iter( sec ):
        if "AHMEDNAGAR" in item.text:
            maharashtra.append(row)
        row = row + 1
    col = col+1
for entry in maharashtra:
    col=0
    entrydata = {}
    for sec in sections:
        entrydata[sec] = fetched[sec][entry]
        col = col + 1
    maharashtradata.append(entrydata)

for flag in maharashtradata:
    if flag['M_Flag'] == "U":
        print "Hello"
```

Here maharashtradata is a list which contains dictionary in it.

The program is not print Hello !

Comment: Well like the error says, `data1` is a string, which doesn't have a `has_key` method. Note that even if it did, it would return a boolean, which would never be equal to "U". Perhaps you should explain exactly what you are trying to do here (and cut out the rest of the irrelevant code).

Comment: In dic i.e entrydata has key 'M_Flag' whose value are either I or U, I am trying to get only that data where key 'M-Flag' has value "U"                              @Daniel Roseman

Comment: Thanks for editing @Dinesh Suthar

Answer (score 0):

If this program is not printing **Hello**, Which means either dictionary inside  maharashtradata list doesn't contain the key **M_Flag** or value of **M_Flag** key is not equal to **U**.

For debugging, Please try to print the maharashtra and maharashtradata lists and check whether lists contains proper data.

Comment: maharashtradata is a list which contains dict @Dinesh Suthar

Comment: Dictionary inside maharashtradict, does not contain M_Flag key. because of this, it is not printing Hello. Please try to print maharashtradata list.

Comment: I printed maharashtradata and I am getting both key and value!                        @Dinesh Suthar

Comment: does dictionary contain M_Flag key?

Comment: Yes dictionary contain M_Flag key

Comment: And what is the value of M_Flag Key ?

Comment: I and U,  also I am printing flag['M_Flag'] before if statement I am getting value

Comment: Does it mean .. there are multiple keys with M_Flag? Can you provide the sample output of dict with M_Flag key.

Comment: I am not able to provide you the output because its too long!

Comment: I am not able to provide you the output because its too long!                                 I will give example as follow                                                                                maharashtradata [{'M_Flag': "I"},{'M_Flag': "I"},{'M_Flag': "U"},{'M_Flag': "U"}]

Comment: Thanks for your time @Dinesh Suthar                                                               Problem resolved as values contain white space so I have to perform trim op.